# SPARQL Query to second and third level with concat

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

[[image: enter image description here] So here 2 parts can have 1 CR and each CR can have multiple ChangeLogs[1]]I have a Tree Structure with three levels currently I am able to get the first level data from the the query written below I am looking for a query that can help me to concat data for ?o and their respective ?s ?p and ?o and even drill down to third level if needed

I have tried it with construct query but want it in a specific format do trying it out with select and `concat`

```
construct{ ?CR ?p ?cOBJECT .} 
where {
    select ?CR ?p (group_concat(?o;separator=',') as ?cOBJECT)
    where{ VALUES ?p {abc:hasPart abc:hasLog abc:Description abc:CRStatus abc:hasSB abc:hasTB}
        ?CR ?p ?o .      
    }    
    GROUP BY ?CR ?p
}
```

Comment: Sample data + expected output would be useful here ... but somehting like that, just add triple patterns and concat whatever you want (here I used `?o1`) : `select ?CR ?p (group_concat(concat(str(?o), str(o1)),;separator=',') as ?cOBJECT)
    where{ VALUES ?p {abc:hasPart abc:hasLog abc:Description abc:CRStatus abc:hasSB abc:hasTB}
        ?CR ?p ?o .      OPTIONAL {?o ?p1 ?o1}
    }    
    GROUP BY ?CR ?p` - if you need it in the RDF later (e.g. `?cOBJECT ?p1 ?o1` or the like), then it's probably more complicated, but without seeing an example I'm too confused now

Comment: Actually the 2nd level is a list and not a single node, if I try to run the code above it repeats str(o1) in all the predicates of ?CR

Comment: I have just another question suppose I have a data that I get from sparql query and I need to provide it to my user in specific format apart from parsing the output is there a direct way to format your data?